# Deploy a Vue container (front-end) and Django container (back-end) in Google Cloud along with a Reverse Proxy container

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

I have an application that I am trying to deploy at Google Cloud.
This application is composed by three Docker containers: Reverse Proxy (ngxin), Back-end (django), and Front-end (vue).

I have to build the front-end giving the IP of the reverse proxy, since the front-end will be running at user's browser, and the user only will know the reverse proxy, my application entry-point. The reverse proxy know how to route the request to the back-end.

It is working just fine locally because I know previously the IP of the reverse proxy (my own local machine).
However, how could I know previously which IP Google Cloud will give to my reverse-proxy before I build and run it?

I need this IP to make the front-end communicates to the back-end through the reverse proxy.

Following the schema of the application.

[image]

Comment: I just realized that I can use Google DNS API to easily solve my problem.

Comment: please could you post an actual answer with the solution to your issue?

Comment: Hello @trung. I found an easier solution before apply Google DNS.
The problem was about how to make the front-end communicates to the back-end through the reverse proxy without knowning its address previously.

Since I use the reverse-proxy it does not actually matter what is its IP address. I can get it dinamically throuh `window.location.href` from the browser.
Next, I build any HTTP request to the reverse-proxy directly since it knows how to route to the back-end.